# ElementRef is undefined only when routing to component

Tags: angular

im using Google Maps Places Autocomplete on my "userUpdate" form component
following this [:http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/)

although im using the reactive approach

everything works fine after im doing f5 on my `http://localhost:4200/user/edit`
route.
however when in routing from main page i get this:

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

and the page doesn't get loaded.
here is my input tag (see #search):

```xml
<input type="text"
  id="hometownCity"
  class="form-control form-control-lg mr-2"
  placeholder="search for location"
  autocorrect="off"
  autocapitalize="OFF"
  spellcheck="off"
  formControlName="city"
  #search>
```

in my class

```js
@ViewChild("search")
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
```

onInit (or viewInit - tried both):

```js
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
 let autocomplete = new 
  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
          types: ["(cities)"]
        });
        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            //get the place result
            let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();  
          });
        });
      });
```

I get the error on `this.searchElementRef.nativeElement`

**Update:**

Added a [plunker example](https://embed.plnkr.co/vWpwb1ocgZIuGahMzsN5/)!

Comment: did it try `afterNgAfterViewInit`

Comment: thanks - yes i tried. the same!

Comment: Where this `this.mapsAPILoader.load()` call is located? I mean could you please provide the whole class and the template?

Comment: thanks roman!
its is a big class.
 this method is in afterNgAfterViewInit.  that what you ment?

Comment: There is nothing about to thank me yet :) I just make guesses what may be the reason of the problem. For exmaple, you use `afterViewInit` but input is in a content of another inner component. In that case you need to use `afterContentInit`. Or simply the search was deleted or not shown at the right moment.

Comment: hey,tried afterContentInit - same.
im not getting why the html is not rendering after router,
however with F5 it is (even with error sometimes)

Comment: could be somthing with zone?
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (

Comment: do you have any *ngIf around the search input tag?

Comment: Please either post a plunker either complete your snippets to reveal more relevant parts

Comment: AS noted by @VikhyathMaiya, i've seen this sort of error before when the ViewChild  element is wrapped by an ngIf and therefore doesn't exist  at the time of ngOninit

Comment: hey, thanks! 
no ngif
added plunker!

Comment: there is no input tag with #search !!please check your plunk

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya fix - thanks
and there is a ng if i missed..ill try remove!

Comment: yes - ngif is the problem

Comment: glad to help ...